# SVG - positioning won't work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, svg

I am new to SVG. I think there are two ways for me to insert SVG icons in my wordpress template.

1.: with "use"

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <use xlink:href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/icons/download.svg#Layer_1"></use>
     </svg>
```

2.: as PHP file

```
get_template_part("icons/download")
```

("get_template_part" in this case refers to a "icon.php" file with the XML code that draws the SVG:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="40px" height="33.999px" viewBox="0 0 40 33.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 40 33.999;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;" d="M39,14h-1v15.999c0,2.209-1.791,4-4,4H6c-2.209,0-4-1.791-4-4V14H1
 c-0.552,0-1-0.448-1-1c0-0.552,0.448-1,1-1h1v-0.001h2v18c0,1.104,0.895,2,2,2h28c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2v-18h2V12h1
 c0.552,0,1,0.448,1,1C40,13.552,39.552,14,39,14z M20.708,13.706c-0.001,0.001-0.002,0.002-0.003,0.002l-0.009,0.009l0,0l0,0
 c-0.087,0.087-0.189,0.147-0.294,0.196c-0.005,0.002-0.009,0.007-0.014,0.009c-0.369,0.163-0.814,0.098-1.117-0.205l-4.989-4.994
 c-0.394-0.394-0.394-1.033,0-1.427c0.394-0.394,1.032-0.394,1.426,0L19,10.591V1c0-0.552,0.448-1,1-1c0.552,0,1,0.448,1,1v9.56
 l3.261-3.264c0.393-0.394,1.031-0.394,1.425,0s0.394,1.033,0,1.427L20.708,13.706z"/>
</svg>
```

The first option doesn't work in IE (even 11!) without javascript.

The second option works in IE9 and above, **that's cool!** but i am not able to position this SVG. i have put it in a wrapper (".svg-wrapper") and tried to position it with CSS but the SVG appears outside of the wrapper in DOM :-(

Am i doing something wrong here?

```
echo '<li class="alignmiddle"><a href="' . $url . '" class="download cf">' . '<div class="svgwrapper">' . get_template_part("icons/download") . '</div>' . $title . '.' . $path_info['extension'] . '<span class="filesize">&nbsp;(' . $filesize . ')</span>' . '</a></li>';
```

Or is there a better solution at all?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code which allows you to define a fallback for older browsers. This method allows you to apply CSS in the same way you would a normal image. As SVG's are vector based you must assign a width and height.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/example.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/example.png'" alt="" />
```

Comment: I can not do this because i use a CMS and the customer should be able to choose a color for the icons in the theme. When i use "img src" i am not able to do this with "color:# ..." or "fil: # ...".